# Label in UITableCellView.contentView showing two times when using autoresizing

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using Grouped UITableView and add UITableViewCells two UILabel's and adding them to the contentView of the cell.  I am also implementing edit mode in my app on this UITableView.

I use the
`lblDetail.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;` in order to decrease width of the text so the delete red button showing in edit mode will not cover my text.

Now what I see is when I scroll my table not in edit mode the labels show two times as if it is in in edit mode and out of edit mode at the same time.

This is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }


    CGRect DetailLabelFrame = CGRectMake(52, 25, 200, 35);
    CGRect TitleLabelFrame = CGRectMake(52, 5, 200, 25);

    lblDetail = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];

    lblDetail.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    lblTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    lblDetail.frame = DetailLabelFrame;
    lblDetail.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblDetail.numberOfLines = 2;

    lblTitle.frame = TitleLabelFrame;    
    lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblTitle.frame = TitleLabelFrame;

    [lblDetail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]];
    [lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT"  size:15]];

    lblDetail.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;

    lblTitle.text = @"054-9700583"; 
    lblDetail.text = @"שאלה:במה אפשר לעזור לך?";

   [cell.contentView addSubview:lblDetail];
   [cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl.png"];

    [lblDetail release];
    [lblTitle release];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];


CGRect DetailLabelFrame = CGRectMake(52, 25, 200, 35);
CGRect TitleLabelFrame = CGRectMake(52, 5, 200, 25);

lblDetail = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];

lblDetail.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
lblTitle.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

lblDetail.frame = DetailLabelFrame;
lblDetail.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblDetail.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblDetail.numberOfLines = 2;

lblTitle.frame = TitleLabelFrame;    
lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblTitle.frame = TitleLabelFrame;

[lblDetail setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14]];
[lblTitle setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT"  size:15]];

lblDetail.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
lblTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblDetail];
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblTitle];

lblDetail.tag = 10;
lblTitle.tag = 11;

}


lblDetail = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10];

lblTitle = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:11];

lblTitle.text = @"054-9700583"; 
lblDetail.text = @"שאלה:במה אפשר לעזור לך?";

cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0;
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl.png"];

[lblDetail release];
[lblTitle release];

return cell;
}
```

Your cell contents was overlapping may be it will help you.Still now if you face same problem the knock me without any hesitation.

Comment: It solved my problem!! the only thing i needed to change is i needed to delete [lblDetail release];
[lblTitle release]; and it is working, so now is it good to release in the dealloc?

Answer (score 1):

If this is only happening when you're scrolling it may be because when a cell is being reused it's creating a new set of labels in addition to what's already in the reused cell.

What you can try to do is move these two lines into your if (cell == nil ) block:

```
lblDetail = [[UILabel alloc]init];
lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc]init];
```

That way when a cell is being reused it'll continue to use the existing lblDetail and lblTitle instead of creating a new one.